# how to post on facebook by using facebook api

Tags: android, facebook

i am looking for an easy method to post on facebook by using face book api
i follow all tutorial on 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
but at the end on authentication android screen does not show any popup or any alert on logcat

my target is to post on facebook wall
and i want this action on a button
i also tried this link to post
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

but getting error on line

```
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
```

any help?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?